# Finding Contrapositive of a statement involving an OR condition.

Tags: logic

Let's say I want to find the contrapositive of the statement:

"For all dogs A, B, and C I have, if A and B are male, then B or C are Shibas".

How do you find the ~ of an or statement ?

I think the contrapositive is "For all dogs A, B, and C, if B or C are not shibas, A and B are not male."

Is my reasoning correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's simplify. If X then Y. That means if not Y then not X.

Here you have X = "A and B are male", and Y = "B or C are Shibas".

Then use "De Morgan's laws" to expand out not X and not Y.

For example:  not (R or S) = (not R) and (not S)

Answer (score 0):

A contrapositive is a statement that says that if P is true, then Q is true. The opposite must also be true, meaning if Q is false, P has to be false.

Therefore, the contrapositive has to be

"For all dogs A,B,and C, if B AND C are not shibas, A OR B are not male"

Check [De Morgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) for your reference